# Charts libraries are not working in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React native. I want to show some charts in my dashboard screen. I have tried both **react-native-chart-kit** and **react-native-pie** libraries. But, both are showing me same error. I followed everything as mentioned in the docs.

Here is the code and error. kindly share your ideas.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import {
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
  StackedBarChart
} from "react-native-chart-kit";

const App = props =>
{
  return(
    <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Text>Charts Container</Text>
  <LineChart
data={{
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [
        Math.random() * 100,
        Math.random() * 100,
        Math.random() * 100,
        Math.random() * 100,
        Math.random() * 100,
        Math.random() * 100
      ]
    }
  ]
}}
width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
height={220}
yAxisLabel="$"
yAxisSuffix="k"
yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
chartConfig={{
  backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
  backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
  backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
  decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
  labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
  style: {
    borderRadius: 16
  },
  propsForDots: {
    r: "6",
    strokeWidth: "2",
    stroke: "#ffa726"
  }
}}
bezier
style={{
  marginVertical: 8,
  borderRadius: 16
    }}
  />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: restart your IDE, command line and run the app again. should fix the problem

Comment: @James, I have tried that already. But its not working. I have gone through this docs (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/749#issue-346748283). Followed Xcode instructions and installed pod, now its working fine.